# Spring Cloud Stream - How to implement retry using reactive API?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring Cloud Stream, with RabbitMQ binder and reactive API. The official documentation provides information on how to implement retry using DLQ, which works great but I can't get it to work using reactive streams. Using the code below I only see an error logged but no retry attempts are performed as if the original message was acknowledged.

```java
@StreamListener
@Output(Channels.STATUS)
public Flux<WriteResponse> handle(@Input(WRITE_DATA) Flux<Message<WriteRequestDTO>> stream) {
    return stream
            .doOnNext(m -> log.info("Received {} request", WRITE_DATA))
            .doOnNext(m -> handleDeadQueue(m.getHeaders()))
            .map(this::validateDestination)
            .map(writerService::write)
            .doOnNext(m -> log.info("Write response: {}", m));
}

private WriteRequest validateDestination(WriteRequestDTO request) {
    if (!destinationService.isValidDestination(request)) {
        String message = String.format("Can't process write request '%s': destination doesn't exist", request);
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(message);
    }
    return request;
}

private void handleDeadQueue(Map<String, Object> headers) {
    if (headers.containsKey("x-death")) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> deathList = (List<Map<String, Object>>) headers.get("x-death");
        if (deathList != null && !deathList.isEmpty()) {
            Map<String, Object> death = deathList.get(0);
            if (death != null) {
                Long numberOfDeaths = Long.valueOf(death.get("count").toString());
                if (numberOfDeaths >= properties.getDlqMaxAttempts()) {
                    // giving up - don't send to DLX
                    throw new ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException("Failed after " + numberOfDeaths + " attempts");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Is there an example on how retry should be implemented using reactive API?
- What's the general approach for error-handling using reactive API?

Comment: In this case you absolutely should follow with Reactive Streams recommendation and do all the required logic manually on the provided `Flux` objects. Consider to read Reactor documentation for that purpose: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html

Comment: i am also facing the same issue. it is giving no consumers attached error once an exception is thrown. after that no message is reaching to the processor. Please suggest me what is the solution for this.